# Swift: Reload alamofire request every 10 seconds

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to get information from an alamofire request and I want the information to be updated every 10 seconds. In other words, I want it to refresh. So I want it to repeat the http request every 10 seconds. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self,selector: "execute", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func execute() {
    // insert logic here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [NSTimer](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-make-an-action-repeat-using-nstimer)

Example :

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: #selector(yourUpdatedFunctionHere), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Swift 4 & 5

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0,
                             target: self,
                             selector: #selector(execute),
                             userInfo: nil,
                             repeats: true)
}

@objc func execute() {
    print("Hello")
}
```

*This Will Execute in every 5 seconds*